# send array variable via ajax post request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to process a form via ajax request. The problem is that I have an array variable inside the form and when I process it via serialize to be send via ajax it returns this:

```
email_id%5B%5D=1&email_id%5B%5D=2&test=23
```

That is the result of .serialize.

I am also using multiple select tags for the array variable.

Why am I getting this error and what should I do to avoid and fix it.

```
<select name="email_id[]" id="email_id_0" style="width: 350px;margin-right: 5;">
</select>

function setList(str){
    var postDatas = $('#form'+str+'').serialize();
    alert(postDatas);
    // $('#crm-feedback').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'somewhere/file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: postDatas,
        success: function(data){
            // $('#crm-feedback').html('Saved!').css('color','green');
            alert("test");
        }

    });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do not use serialize. Use POST

Comment: @YourCommonSense POST will still serialize it.

Comment: What *"error"* are you getting? the serialized data you are seeing is correct and valid.

Comment: I am using post, i am using serialize to get all the data of the form.

Comment: @KevinB the %5B%5D, since those should be [], since my select tags have a name="email_id[]"

Comment: but they *are* `[]`. `%5B%5D` == `[]`

Comment: @KevinB if I remove the [] it is send via ajax but with [] it stops.

Comment: the `[]` isn't stopping it from sending. Most likely your server just isn't handling it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following

```
var array = document.getElementById("<your array elem>");
        var formdata = new FormData();
        for(var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
            formdata.append("<key>",array[i]);
        }

        $.ajax(
         {
             url: "<url>",
             dataType: "<expected return datatype>",
             type: "POST",

             data: formdata,
             success: function (result, status) {
                //process success
             },
             error: function (result, status) {
                //process failure
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been having a virtually identical problem today which is now solved thanks to help on here - [read this post and look at the jsfiddles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208160/create-jquery-array-from-input-name-array)